# How do you add a help button to Excel userform

Tags: vba, excel-2007, userform

I have a few different userforms in Excel 2007 right now and was wondering if I could add a "?" button next to the close symbol in the userform.

Alternatively, is there a way to display some text when I hover over a specific label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form property "WhatsThisButton" displays the question mark icon next to the close button, but this does nothing without creating an actual help file and assigning it to your form, this is not an easy thing to do.  Far easier is to display text as you have described, each control has a "controlTipText" property that will display whatever text you enter in there, when your user hovers their mouse over the control